# How to display the line number on a validation error with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I used this [example](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/JTokenIsValidWithMessages.htm) from the official documentation as a basis for my code.

I am validating a json string like this:

```
        var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var schema = JsonSchema.Parse(File.ReadAllText("schema.jsonschema"));
        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText) as JObject;

        IList<string> messages;
        if (!jObj.IsValid(schema, out messages))
        {
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
```

This works, but the error message I'm getting does not contain the offending line number, for example:

```
Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer.
```

The linked example suggests that there should be a line number in the message, but there isn't. Maybe this feature was removed or needs a flag to be set? I would like the output to contain the line number, and the description property of the schema item if possible.

Comment: your code differs slightly from the example in the fact that you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` before calling `.IsValid()`. Does commenting this line make any difference?

Comment: @paul If I actually comment that out then I don't have JObject. But this is really just how I load the json, I could write it in the code as in the example. I'm sure this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: just wondering if there was a difference between `jObj = JObject.Parse(...)` and `jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(...)`

Comment: I don't think so, I can use the resulting jObj just fine in the code elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Json.NET?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, yes. The filename of the zip was Json45r11.zip. Is that not the latest one?

Comment: Have you ever found out about how to do this?

Comment: @RedX unfortunately not. I think I just left it without the line number because bad output was not excepted and the validation itself worked. But it was a long time ago now.